# Variadic template method and std::function - compilation error

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I'm sure the error is very simple and silly, but I can't see one. Here's the code:

```
#include <future>

template <typename ResultType>
class Foo
{
public:
    template <typename ...Args>
    void exec(const std::function<ResultType(Args...)>& task, Args&&... args) {}
};

int main()
{
   Foo<void>().exec([](){});
   return 0;
}
```

And here's the error:

> 'void CAsyncTask::exec(const std::function
>   &,Args &&...)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const
>   std::function &' with [
>   ResultType=void ]

`Foo<void>().exec<void>([](){})` doesn't work either (and I'd much prefer not having to specify the `Args` types manually).

Update regarding the suggested answer: the following code does indeed work.
`CAsyncTask<void>().exec(std::function<void ()>([](){}));`

But is there really no workaround for this problem? Can I expand my template somehow to deduce the lambda arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Pradhan mentionned, the exact type of the `std::function` cannot be inferred from the lambda. You can cast it explicitly to solve the issue:

```
Foo<void>().exec(std::function<void()>([](){}));
```

Alternatively, you can simply use another typename for the function, without creating a `std::function`:

```
template <typename Callable, typename ...Args>
void exec(Callable&& task, Args&&... args);
```

Then `Callable` will accept several types of functors, including lambdas.

Note that there is a small performance penalty in using `std::function` objects in comparison to the template solution.

You could also add a [static_assert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) to ensure that your `Callable` can be called with the given arguments, and display a meaningful message otherwise, rather than letting the compiler generate one at the actual call.

Answer (score 3):

You could try changing exec's signature to

```
template<typename Fn, typename... Args> 
void exec(Fn&& task, Args&&... args)
```

and then construct your std::function inside the function

Comment: Yep, just got the same idea and it works!

Answer (score 2):

A lambada is not a `std::function`, and as such types cannot be deduced from it. You'll want to make the `std::function` part a non-deducible context:

```c++
template<class T>struct identity_t{using type=T;};
template<class T>using identity=typename identity_t<T>::type;

template <typename ResultType>
class Foo
{
public:
    template <typename... Args>
    void exec(const std::function<ResultType(identity<Args>...)>& task,
              Args&&... args)
    {}
};
```

You can also make the function completely generic with template constraints;

```c++
#include <type_traits>

template<class...>struct voider{using type=void;};
template<class... Ts>using void_t=typename voider<Ts...>::type;

template<class T,class=void>
struct callable:std::false_type{};
template<class F,class... Ts>
using invoker=decltype(std::declval<F>()(std::declval<Ts>()...));
template<class F,class... Ts>
struct callable<F(Ts...),void_t<invoker<F,Ts...>>>:std::true_type{};

template<class R,class S>
using result_eq=std::is_same<std::result_of_t<S>,R>;

#define REQUIRE(cond) std::enable_if_t<(cond)>* = nullptr

template<class R>
class Foo
{
public:
    template<class F, class... Args, REQUIRE(callable<F(Args...)>{}), REQUIRE((result_eq<R, F(Args...)>{}))>
    void exec(F&& f, Args&&...);
};

int main()
{
    Foo<void>().exec([] (int) {}, 4);
}
```

Comment: Hmm. This is the second time I see the identity trick, and still don't get it...

Comment: @VioletGiraffe I think it has to do with the fact that functions and structs/classes don't exactly have the same template deduction rules. So we use a struct to deduce the type.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Any parameter that contains a nested name specifier consisting of a template parameter (i.e `void f(typename T::value_type)`) is a non-deduced context. The template parameter will not be deduced by the argument that is passed in. The template alias `identity` is for the cleaner syntax, but what really does the work is `identity_t`. The alias template is replaced with `typename identity_t<T>::type`, which is a nested name specifier, thus making it a non-deduced context. `Args...` will then be deduced only be the second parameter pack, `args...`.